# Transform multi level index dataframe into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have this 2-level index dataframe. I would like to create a nested dictionary from this dataframe.

```
                total_prob
SubType Type              
AAA     A>C   7.393806e-07
        A>G   4.823150e-06
        A>T   9.559154e-07
AAC     A>C   6.728159e-07
        A>G   1.772496e-06
        A>T   9.689872e-07
AAG     A>C   1.637682e-06
        A>G   5.986134e-06
        A>T   1.721770e-06
```

Sample output:

```
{'AAA':{'A>C': 7.393806e-07, 'A>G': 4.823150e-06, 'A>T': 9.559154e-07}, 'AAC':{'A>C': 6.728159e-07, 'A>G': 1.772496e-06, 'A>T': 9.689872e-07}, 'AAG':{'A>C': 1.637682e-06, 'A>G': 5.986134e-06, 'A>T': 1.721770e-06}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Assume your dataframe is `df`

```
SubType Type  total_prob
0     AAA  A>C           2
1     NaN  A>G           3
2     NaN  A>T           4
3     AAC  A>C           5
4     NaN  A>G           6
5     NaN  A>T           7
6     AAG  A>C           8
7     NaN  A>G           9
8     NaN  A>T          10
```

you can [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill the missing values with forward method.Next groupby and make the json output.

```
df = df.fillna(method="ffill")   
res = df.groupby(["SubType"]).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(list(x.Type),list(x.total_prob)))).to_json(orient="index")
```

output

```
'{"AAA":{"A>C":2,"A>G":3,"A>T":4},"AAC":{"A>C":5,"A>G":6,"A>T":7},"AAG":{"A>C":8,"A>G":9,"A>T":10}}'
```